# upload multiple images in a loop in android

Tags: android

I am trying to upload more than 70 images.I can upload only 19 images at a time as the server allows maximum of 19 files only.SO I tried to loop image upload process in a loop within intent service .But It uploads only 1st 19 images then it enters the loop but I get the following :

```
I/System.out(1234): [CDS]rx timeout:50000
I/System.out(1234 ): [socket][1] connection www.example.com:80;LocalPort=1234(50000)
I/System.out(1234 ): [CDS]connect[www.example.com/100.00.00.000:80] tm:50
 D/Posix(1234): [Posix_connect Debug]Process www.example:80 
I/System.out(1234 ): [socket][/192.168.0.0:1234] connected
 I/System.out(1234 ): [CDS]rx timeout:50000
```

The first loop executes properly but second loop onwards I get the above exception.
How to make it work in a loop.Also,I have added :

```
private static final long CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 50000;
    private static final int SO_TIMEOUT = 50000;

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONN_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SO_TIMEOUT);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

How can I make it work.I really appreciate any help.

Comment: did you try to increase  CONN_TIMEOUT or SO_TIMEOUT ?

Comment: another idea , can you make execute uploading in separate thread.

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConfiguration.java  "connManager" maxPerRoute wigh low value around 5 should manage your constraint server-side